# calling a sub using checkboxes excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, public

I'm trying to call a sub using this code

```
If CheckBox2 = True Then Call Qorep
```

Heres the sub :

```
Public Sub Qorep()

For i = 0 To cap
    Hoja9.Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = Empty
    array_Qorep(i, 0) = Hoja1.Range("B" & i + 2)

    Select Case Hoja9.Cells(3, 5)
    Case Is > 0
    If array_Qorep(i, 0) < Hoja9.Cells(3, 5) Then Hoja9.Cells(i + 2, 3) = array_Qorep(i, 0)
    End Select

    Select Case Hoja9.Cells(3, 4)
    Case Is > 0
    If array_Qorep(i, 0) > Hoja9.Cells(3, 4) Then Hoja9.Cells(i + 2, 3) = array_Qorep(i, 0)
    End Select
    If Hoja9.Cells(i + 2, 3) = Empty Then Hoja9.Cells(i + 2, 3) = "#N/A"
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem is that with the checkbox checked it doesn't do anything, is there a problem trying to call the sub?
im a beginner and i might not be able to see whats wrong, any help?

Comment: same problem, if i add `()` it will delete itself automatically

Comment: Where is the line "if ...." Placed in the workbook?

Comment: pretty much at the beginning of the code, after calling all the variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worksheet you need

```
 Private Sub  CheckBox2_Click()

       If CheckBox2 = True Then Call Qorep

   End Sub
```

If your sub is not in the same worksheet then you need to use
Modulename.Qorep